# Most efficient way to sort by multiple fields in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting, recursion

I'm working on a project where I have a table in memory, for example:

```
field1    field2    field3    field4    field5
somevalue somevalue somevalue somevalue somevalue
somevalue somevalue somevalue somevalue somevalue
    .
    . 
    .
    .
    v
```

What is the best way to write a function that would allow a user to specify some non-predetermined permutation of fields by which to sort? (ex./ sort by field2, then field1, then field5). The best method I thought of so far is a recursive function, but it gets ugly pretty quick, especially with creating and managing 'subgroups' of rows within each column. Can somebody point me in a more efficient direction before I commit to this convoluted approach?

By the way, my table is stored as a list of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to realize here is that your search *algorithm* always stays exactly the same. The only thing that changes is your actual comparison function.

I would recommend using a standard sort in the `Arrays` or `Collections` class, but writing your own custom `Comparable` class or `Comparator`, whose `compare` method will use the data the user supplies. This is actually kind of interesting - I've only ever written `Comparable` classes that use fixed data, but this is exactly a use case for them.

All you need to do is write the function

```
public int compare(Row row1, Row row2) {
    // iterate over the columns *in order of the user-supplied priority*
    // return appropriately
}
```

[Here's documentation on the Comparable class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

[And Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Which one you need depends on what you're implementing, I forget the details but should be straightforward.

The key #2 thing here is that you can instantiate your `ColumnPrioritiesComparable` class *before* the priorities are set. e.g.

```
class ColPriComp implements Comparable<ColPriComp> {
    private volatile int[] priorities; // possibly static, or obtained some other way,
    // so there's only one shared among all classes

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ColPriComp other) {
        // use "priorities" to do the comparison
    }

    public void setPriorities(int[] newPriorities) {
        this.priorities = newPriorities;
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, a `Comparator` would specify how to sort the table under a specific permutation. This would mean that I would need to implement a `Comparator` for every possible scenario. If I am wrong please correct me.I need something more general, a method that would be able to take on any possible permutation of fields to sort by.

Comment: @Mike think more object-oriented. you will only need to *write* the custom code once, but it may use data that will change between when the object is instantiated and when it is sorted.

Comment: @Mike e.g. a `CustomSortable` class that will have `private int columnPriorities[];` as a data member, which will be used by the `compare` method, and a `setPriorities(int[] newPriorities)` method. So the behavior of the `compare` method changes after the setter is called.